# React Native TextInput Hiding when clicking on a child View

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to generate recommendations when the user types in a text, much like the tags in stackoverflow. Problem is: when I click on one of my suggested tags, the keyboard is hiding, even though I put keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'always'} into my scrollView. Other TextInputs are working

https://gifyu.com/image/lgl9

The Tag suggestions get generated by a FlatList, might that be a problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your code but you should add marginBottom in the container.

constructor

```
 Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', frames => {
      if (!frames.endCoordinates) {
        return;
      }
      this.setState({keyboardSpace: frames.endCoordinates.height});
    });
    Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', frames => {
      this.setState({keyboardSpace: 0});
    });
```

render

```
 <ScrollView style={[Styles.scrollStyle, {marginBottom: this.state.keyboardSpace}]}>
  ...
  <TextInput />
  ...
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the right approach, but can you try to manually invoke `focus` method ([refer this](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#focus)) on the `TextInput` in question in the `onPress` handler of your `FlatList`?

Maybe that helps.